# Apache Spark UDF that returns dynamic data types

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have `UDF` that processes JSON and returns dynamic data results per row. In my case I need this to validate data and return validated data.

The schema is flexible for each row. This means I cannot create `case class` for every case (some of my data can be nested).

I've tried to return tuple from my UDF function, but I had no luck in this either (because I needed to convert from list to tuple), and I didn't find an elegant solution for that.

The data types that I'm returning are `String`, `Integer`, `Double`, `DateTime`, in different order.

I've tried to use `map` on DataFrame, but having issues with my schema.

```
import spark.implicits._

def processData(row_type: String) = {
  /*
  completely random output here. Tuple/List/Array of 
  elements with a type Integer, String, Double, DateType.
  */

  // pseudo-code starts here

  if row_type == A
     (1, "second", 3)
  else
     (1, "second", 3, 4)
}

val processDataUDF = udf((row_type: String) => processData(row_type))

val df = Seq((0, 1), (1, 2)).toDF("a", "b")
val df2 = df.select(processDataUDF($"a"))
df2.show(5)
df2.printSchema()
```

Results

```
+------------+
|      UDF(a)|
+------------+
|[1,second,3]|
|[1,second,3]|
+------------+
```

How how should I approach this problem? We have different processing results per `row_type`. All the `row_type`'s are set dynamically. I can great `Schema` for each `row_type`, but I cannot make same UDF return results with different schemas.

Is using `map` is the only approach here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spark `Dataset` is a columnar data structure and there is really no place for a flexible schema here. Schema has to be homogeneous (all rows have to have the same general structure) and known upfront (if you use UDF it has to return well defined SQL type).

You can achieve some flexibility by:

- Defining schema which represents a superset of all possible fields and mark individual columns as `nullable`. This is possible only if there are no type conflicts (if `Row` contains field `foo` it is always represented using the same SQL type).
- Using collection types (`MapType`, `ArrayType`) to represent fields with variable size. All values and / or keys have to be of the same type.
- Reshaping raw data to the point where it is actually representable with fixed schema. Spark includes, as its dependency, [`json4s`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s), which provides a set of tools for [merging, diffing](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#merging--diffing) and [querying](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#querying-json) JSON data. It can be used to apply relatively complex transformations if needed.

If this is not practical I would recommend keeping JSON field "as is" and parsing it only on-demand to extract specific values. You can use `get_json_object` and explicit type casting. This allows for testing different scenarios:

```
coalesce(Seq("$.bar", "$.foo.bar", "$.foobar.foo.bar")
  .map(get_json_object($"json_col", _)): _*).cast(DoubleType)
```

without assuming a single document structure.

You can get a bit more flexibility with binary `Encoders` (`Encoders.kryo`, `Encoders.java`) or `RDD` API, which can be used to store union types (or even `Any`), but if you really expect *completely random output*, it suggests some serious design or data modeling problem. Even if you can store parsed data it will be really hard to work with it.